# How to get first and second part of a string in bash on last occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: bash

I need to split a string on the last occurrence of a delimiter and get both the parts into two variables.

Input could be

```
- stringOne_One/stringOne_Two/stingOne_Three
- stringTwo_One/stringTwo_Two
```

I want to split the string on the last occurrence of the delimiter "/" and get both the first and the last part of the string into two variables.

For the first example output should be

```
var1=stringOne_One/stringOne_Two
var2=stringOne_Three
```

For the second example, output should be

```
var1=stringTwo_One
var2=stringTwo_Two
```

How do I do this in bash. Would prefer a solution using AWK, but any other method is also acceptable.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @Cyrus: Sorry about that. Will keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ x="stringOne_One/stringOne_Two/stingOne_Three"
$ var1="${x%/*}"
$ var2="${x##*/}"
$ echo "${var1} : ${var2}"
stringOne_One/stringOne_Two : stingOne_Three

$ x="stringTwo_One/stringTwo_Two"
$ var1="${x%/*}"
$ var2="${x##*/}"
$ echo "${var1} : ${var2}"
stringTwo_One : stringTwo_Two
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dirname`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dirname-invocation.html) and [`basename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/basename-invocation.html) like so:

```
my_var='stringOne_One/stringOne_Two/stingOne_Three'

var1=$(basename $my_var)
# stingOne_Three

var2=$(dirname $my_var)
# stringOne_One/stringOne_Two
```

Comment: Accepted @markp-fuso's answer as it can be extended for other delimiters as well.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` and a regex:

```
string='stringOne_One/stringOne_Two/stingOne_Three'

[[ "$string" =~ (.*)/(.*) ]]
var1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
var2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```